# Remove Polygon On Second Click

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygons

When the user clicks on the marker the first time I want a polygon to appear. The second time they click the polygon should disappear. This code works fine for the appearing part but it does not remove the polygon from the map. Every odd click just makes the polygon darker.

```
body onload="initMap()">
<p id="instructions"></p>
<div id="map" style='overflow:hidden;height:500px;width:500px;'></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initMap() {
    var myOptions = {zoom:11,center:new google.maps.LatLng(37.55020520861464,126.98140242753904),mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);

    document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
        initMarker();
        myTimer();
    });
}
    function initMarker() {
        var t1 = 1;
    marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.55020520861464,126.98140242753904)});
    marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.558816, 126.908212)});
    marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.580107, 127.056797)});
    marker4 = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.446290, 126.862625)});
    marker5 = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.435041, 126.999528)});
    marker6 = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.522926, 126.853862)});

    marker1.addListener('click', function() {
          var triangleCoords = [
        {lat: 37.550, lng: 123.9814},
        {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118},
        {lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757},
        {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190}
        ];

        var triangle1 = new google.maps.Polygon({
            paths: triangleCoords,
            strokeColor: 'FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 0.35
        });
        if (t1 == 1) {
            triangle1.setMap(map);
            t1 = 2;
        }
        else {
            triangle1.setMap(null);
            t1 = 1;
        }
    });
}

</script>
<div><button id="myButton">Start</button></div>
<div id="timer"></div>
<p id="explain"></p>
<script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp'
async defer ></script>
</body>
```

Comment: You may want to a look at the [containsLocation method](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation).

Comment: Duplicate of [Removing Rectangle from Map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36632783/removing-rectangle-from-map), same issue, same solution.

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: myTimer is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the new polygon inside the if statement. I think, when ever you evoke that function it makes a new instance of triangle1, that's why when you try to remove polygon it deletes the new instance of "var triangle1" (which wasn't drawn to to map yet) rather than the one on the map. (sorry about the English)

```
marker1.addListener('click', function() {
          var triangleCoords = [
        {lat: 37.550, lng: 123.9814},
        {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118},
        {lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757},
        {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190}
        ];


        if (t1 == 1) {
            var triangle1 = new google.maps.Polygon({
             paths: triangleCoords,
             strokeColor: 'FF0000',
             strokeOpacity: 0.8,
             strokeWeight: 2,
             fillColor: '#FF0000',
             fillOpacity: 0.35
            });
            triangle1.setMap(map);
            t1 = 2;
        }
        else {
            triangle1.setMap(null);
            t1 = 1;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

One option (from [Removing Rectangle from Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36632783/removing-rectangle-from-map), slightly modified...

1. define the `triangle1` variable outside the scope of the click listener
2. check if the `triangle1` object exists and has a `.setMap` method.
3. if it does, set it's map property to `null` (the polygon is currently displayed), hide it, and set it to null.
4. if it doesn't exist, or doesn't have a `.setMap` method, create the marker.

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.55020520861464, 126.98140242753904),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);

  document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
    initMarker();
  });
}

function initMarker() {
  marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    title: "marker 1",
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.55020520861464, 126.98140242753904)
  });
  var triangle1;
  marker1.addListener('click', function(evt) {
    if (triangle1 && triangle1.setMap) {
      triangle1.setMap(null);
      triangle1 = null;
    } else {
      var triangleCoords = [{
        lat: 37.550,
        lng: 123.9814
      }, {
        lat: 18.466,
        lng: -66.118
      }, {
        lat: 32.321,
        lng: -64.757
      }, {
        lat: 25.774,
        lng: -80.190
      }];

      triangle1 = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: triangleCoords,
        strokeColor: 'FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map
      });
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div>
  <button id="myButton">Start</button>
</div>
<div id="timer"></div>
<p id="explain"></p>
<div id="map"></div>
```